# Images in html response not shown in chrome extension

Tags: html, postman

When the response includes html with images, and those images have a `src` attribute in the form of a url, the Chrome-extension version of Postman displays a "broken image" icon (like the one on the line below).

[image]

When using a native version (tried linux and windows), images contained in the html response are displayed.

Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: the image link is correct... its an image of a "broken image" icon